# Don't interrupt script in sh ("try-finally" for sh scripts)

Tags: shell-script, signal

I'm trying to make a simple script to wrap a command in such a way that it runs with a swapped screen. The main target is `top` but I wanted it to be a general wrapper.

I got it running fine with *bash* but I want to make it work with *dash*, *ash* or any other simple shell that can be used as `/bin/sh`. The issue is that when I interrupt the wrapped command with Ctrl+C, that interrupts the script as well.

The *bash* script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
tput smcup
( "$@" )
status=$?
tput rmcup
exit $status
```

I know that I could have used the *bash* command `trap` but that would have made it even more *bash*-specific, and that's exactly what I'm attempting to avoid.

Curiously enough, with *busybox sh* it works as intended as well.

So, is there a way I can get it working with any other *sh*-type shell without getting interrupted when I interrupt the command in execution, so that the `tput rmcup` command will always be executed?

Note: I've read the questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961389/exception-handling-in-shell-scripting and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656492/linux-shell-try-catch-finally but neither answered this.

Comment: Try using screen : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNU_Screen

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help as `screen` has the same problem: I lose the previous contents of the terminal screen when I detach it.